# what is the name of this new c++ syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I just saw a new C++ syntax like:

```
x = "abc"s;
```

From context I guessed that this means x was assigned a string "abc", I would like to know the name of this new syntax, and is there any similar syntax in C++1z?

Comment: [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) (since C++14).

Comment: you mean the operator""s???

Comment: Much thanks for the answer, I think this answer is exactly what I am looking for, please put this as an answer for me to approve :).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, they've been around since C++11. They're called [user-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal). This specific literal was standardized in [C++14](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s), however, it is easy to roll your own.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    std::string s1 = "abc\0\0def";
    std::string s2 = "abc\0\0def"s;
    std::cout << "s1: " << s1.size() << " \"" << s1 << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "s2: " << s2.size() << " \"" << s2 << "\"\n";
}
```

For example, to make your own std::string literal, you could do (note, all user-defined literals must start with an underscore):

```
std::string operator"" _s(const char* s, unsigned long n)
{
    return std::string(s, n);
}
```

To use the example I gave, simply do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string operator"" _s(const char* s, unsigned long n)
{
    return std::string(s, n);
}


int main(void)
{
    auto s = "My message"_s;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps replace "added" with "standardised"?: it was possible to do this yourself in C++11.

Comment: thank you, is there any other user-defined literals with similar syntax?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Have an upvote.

Comment: @Bathsheba Edited, I'll add an example. You can roll your own. std::chrono uses them too, a lot.

Comment: Cool, much thanks.

Comment: How would you use that operator you gave as an example?

Comment: @moooeeeep, I added an example.

Comment: @Bathsheba could you?  I thought all user defined literals have to start with an `_`?

Comment: @Curious: You're correct. (Personally I think user defined literals was a mere indulgence on the part of the standards committee. Did we *really* need this, at the expense of modules for example?)